# Browser does not download the CSV file i created

Tags: angular, download

I am working on a web project. I use Spring Boot and Angular 2. I want to create CSV file and download this file on client pc from server. I use Apache Poi to create the CSV file. When I click on the 'Export CSV' button I can pass from frontend to backend via service and I can create the CSV file on the server successfully. Here is service code:

```
exportCSVFileTest(parameter: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.post( super.getAddrApi() + parameter , null )
        .catch( err => {
            if (!err.status) {
                err = {
                    status: Observable.throw(401)
                };
            }
            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
}
```

After I use this service, I create the CSV file on server and I try to download this file on client's pc from server:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename=" + file.getName());
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        while(is.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
        {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }

        is.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

After that I don't get any error. Everything seems fine however the window that should appear for the file uploading process does not appear. I tried different methods, for example I set content type `application/csv` or `text/csv`. And I tried 'OutputStream', '`response.getWriter().write()`' vs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please flag the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download a file you need to tell the browser it is a download, I know 2 ways to do this:

**1 - Download the file using a link in the HTML**

```
<a [routerLink]="['url/to/download/the/file']">Download CSV</a>
```

**2 - Get the file using your service and downloading with [saveAs](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library**

```
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';

this.service.exportCSVFileTest('parameter').subscribe(response => {
    const filename = 'name of the file.csv';
    saveAs(response.blob(), filename);
})
```

Hope this help.